# Assign custom row value in sql query

Tags: mysql

I am having multipe tables + different fields and I try to do something like this:

```
SELECT
   `title` as title,
   `manufacturer`+`model` as content /* I want to achieve this as well */
   `type` = 'auto_table' /* custom variable w/ value auto_table to know from where is this data*/
    FROM `auto`
    WHERE `title` LIKE '%bmw%'
    OR
    `manufacturer` LIKE '%bmw'
    OR
    `other_data` LIKE '%bmw'
UNION
    SELECT
       `title` as title,
       `content` as content
       `type` = 'news_page' /* custom variable w/ value news_page to know from where is this data*/
        FROM `news`
        WHERE `title` LIKE '%bmw%'
        OR
        `content` LIKE '%bmw'
```

I mean I want to add a row with its value during select on the fly.
Another one I want to combine two fields into one like `manufacturer`+`model` as `title`

Comment: And the programming question is ...?

Comment: Use `concate` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT (manufacturer, model) as content`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   title,
   CONCAT(manufacturer,model) as content
   'auto_table' as type
FROM [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to get what you're really after. Is it that you want to insert-select in one go?

```
INSERT INTO your_table
SELECT
   `title` as title,
   CONCAT(`manufacturer`,' ', `model`) as content /* I want to achieve this as well */
   `type` = 'auto_table' /* custom variable w/ value auto_table to know from where is this data*/
    FROM `auto`
    WHERE `title` LIKE '%bmw%'
    OR
    `manufacturer` LIKE '%bmw'
    OR
    `other_data` LIKE '%bmw'
UNION
    SELECT
       `title` as title,
       `content` as content
       `type` = 'news_page' /* custom variable w/ value news_page to know from where is this data*/
        FROM `news`
        WHERE `title` LIKE '%bmw%'
        OR
        `content` LIKE '%bmw'
```

Use CONCAT  to concatenate values